# In jmeter is it possible get the test start time on all remote servers (time should be the same on all servers)?

Tags: jmeter

If I have jmeter running with 4 remote servers (load generators) and 1 local server (controller) is there a way I can pass a timestamp from the local controller to all 4 remote servers?

I want to create a screenshots directory on each of the remote servers with the timestamp including seconds. Im creating a new directory for every test that is run and need the directory to be the same across all 4 remote servers. The test plans run locally so calling __time() gets the local time of each server and is not usually exactly the same.

Comment: Can't you sync all your remotes and controller to a time server?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property at jmeter startup on the controller, which holds the system time.

Use option -G so that the remotes get the property.

ie something like -Gserver_time=%date%_%time% (windows), then use ${__P{server_time}} in your directory name on the remotes.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. This does not really do what I want however. After opening jmeter I can start and stop many tests and I want to pass a different value to the remote server each time a new test is started. Your method would allow me to pass 1 value then I would have to close jmeter and start it again.

Comment: this implies you are using jmeter in GUI mode, which is intended for test and development rather than actual performance testing. don't think you can easily pass a value between controller and remotes the way you need. you can derive the remote time offset based on the server_time passed a timestamp on each remote (maybe the time the jmeter-server process was created?), then use that to create a relative_time from server_time. or use an increment for the directory name, then use the actual timestamp in the filesystem to determine test time.

Comment: I run the controller in gui mode because I wrote a plugin that gives me aggregate results which are better than any other visualizers I have been able to find. The load generators are all running in server mode. The only way I can think of to get the exact same time on all load generators is if they call back to a service on the controller which somehow tracks the start of the test. Using a time server will not work because basically all the load generators will start the test at different times (one might start 5 ms after the last) so a time server is no better than System.currentTimeMilli().

Comment: I don't think JMeter is designed to work the way you have expected. Perhaps redesign your plugin to work with jtl files, so it can adjust times during aggregation.  Or have a look at http://jmeter-plugins.org/ for more listeners and results manipulation and display (graphs, etc).